# What are the overheads of humongous functions?

Tags: javascript, performance, function

How much overhead is there when use functions that have a *huge* body?

For example, consider this piece of code:

```
(function() {
    // 25k lines
})();
```

How may it affect loading speed / memory consumption?

Comment: Do you mean overhead in terms of memory or time?

Comment: I'd tend to say negligible, especially if we speak about 1 function

Comment: You should probably create your own test and see. You could try: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: @pacerier what in the actual ef?

Comment: @quamrana, regarding both of course.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest I'm not sure, the good way to help answer your question is to measure.

You can use a javascript profiler, such as the one built into Google Chrome, here is a [mini intro to the google chrome profiler](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/profiles.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Firebug `profiler()` and `time()`: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/02/02/profiling-javascript-with-firebug-console-profile-console-time/

Answer (score 3):

Overhead is negligible on a static function declaration regardless of size. The only performance loss comes from what is defined inside the function.

Yes, you will have large closures that contain many variables, but unless your declaring several tens of thousands of private variables in the function, or executing that function tens of thousands of times, then you won't notice a difference.

The real question here is, if you split that function up into multiple smaller functions, would you notice a performance increase? The answer is no, you should actually see a slight performance *decrease* with more overhead, although your memory allocation should at least be able to collect some unused variables.

Either way, javascript is most often only bogged down by obviously expensive tasks, so I wouldn't bother optimizing until you see a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well that's almost impossible to answer.
If you realy want to understand about memory usage, automatic garbage colection and other nitty gritty of closure, start here: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, products like JQuery are built on using closures extremely heavily. JQuery is considered to be a very high performance piece of Javascript code. This should tell you a lot about the coding techniques it uses.

The exact performance of any given feature is going to vary between different browsers, as they all have their own scripting engines, which are all independantly written and have different optimisations. But one thing they will all have done is tried to give the best optimisations to the most commonly used Javascript features. Given the prevelance of JQuery and its like, you can bet that closures are very heavily optimised.

And in any case, with the latest round of browser releases, their scripting engines are all now sufficiently high performance that you'd be hard pushed to find anything in the basic language constructs which consitutes a significant performance issue.